# How to show unity ads banner in flutter

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine

I have an app which I developed in flutter. I want to show a unity banner ads only in the bottom navigation bar of the app. Code snippet will be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is plugin you can use that https://pub.dev/packages/unity_ads_plugin

```
    UnityBannerAd(
      placementId: 'PLACEMENT_ID',
      onLoad: (placementId) => print('Banner loaded: $placementId'),
      onClick: (placementId) => print('Banner clicked: $placementId'),
      onFailed: (placementId, error, message) => print('Banner Ad $placementId failed: $error $message'),
)
```

Comment: Hi when I used the code you gave me my app crashed. Take a look at it: - bottomNavigationBar:UnityBannerAd(placementId: AdHelper.bannerId,
      onLoad: (placementId) => print('Banner loaded: $placementId'),
      onClick: (placementId) => print('Banner clicked: $placementId'),
      onFailed: ((placementId, error, errorMessage) => print('Banner Ad $placementId failed: $errorMessage')),
      ),

Comment: See the example https://pub.dev/packages/unity_ads_plugin/example